# How to automate the compression of the contents of each subfolder in a directory?

Tags: files, directory, automation, compression

I'm looking to automate the compression of the contents of each subfolder (excluding the subfolder itself) in a directory, with each .zip of said contents corresponding to each subfolder. Is there a way to do such a thing in Ubuntu 22.04? The output consisting of .zip files could be in each subfolder or all of them in a location, I don't care.

Example: the code would read/get the contents of subfolder 1 and zip them, then do the same for subfolder 2, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the current directory contains only the subdirectories you want to zip, then the easiest would be:

```bash
for d in *; do zip -r $d.zip $d; done
```

However if you run it again with the zip files still there, you'll have a bunch of `.zip.zip` files containing the previous ones.

So let's skip non-directories, and safeguard against spaces in directory names while we're at it:

```bash
for d in *; [ ! -d "$d" ] || do zip -r "$d.zip" "$d"; done
```

If you insist on not having the subdirectory at the top level in the zip file (bad style if you ask me, but I'm a Linux hack), we need to jump into directories (one more reason to prefer `tar` over `zip`):

```bash
for d in *; do
    [ -d "$d" ] && pushd "$d" && zip -r "../$d.zip" . && popd || true
done
```

With `tar` it would be:

```bash
for d in *; do
    [ ! -d "$d" ] || tar -czf "$d.tgz" -C "$d" .
done
```

Or use `tar -cJf "$d.tar"` in there to have massive (but slow) `xz` compression.